# Equivalent of Clean & build in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Today while running an app from Android Studio, it didn't build from my latest code.

I looked for a *Clean & build* option but I couldn't find one.

So my question is: what is Android Studio's equivalent of *Clean & build*?

Comment: I'm observing that whenever I perform the `Clean Project`, the build logs show the it also built the solution after the cleaning operation. I'm using Android Studio v3.1.3. So the clean option should work for clean + build both.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Android studio is based on Intellij Idea. In Intellij Idea you have to do the following from the GUI menu.

```
Build -> Rebuild Project
```

Comment: There is no such option in the 'Build' menu.

Answer (score 50):

I don't know if there's a way to get a clean build via the UI, but it's easy to do from the commandline using gradle wrapper. From the root directory of your project:

```
./gradlew clean
```

Comment: This doesn't work for all projects. It seems that some of them which are imported from Eclipse don't use gradlew at all to do builds.

Comment: Very useful in a batch script if you need to deal with large numbers of projects (a semester of student assignments for me)

Answer (score 30):

In latest releases of Android Studio one more option has been added dedicatedly for  Clean.

```
Build > Clean Project
```

Comment: Do you mean in the dev builds?  Latest stable release (1.1) does not have this option (at least on Linux).

Comment: ... neither on Mac.

Comment: @Anticro I could see this in my Mac.

Comment: It seems like it has something to do with the build system in use. For Gradle the menu option is shown. But if that project was created with Eclipse, it's hidden.

Answer (score 18):

Also you can edit your Run/Debug configuration and add `clean` task.

Click on the Edit configuration

[image: Click on the Edit configuration]

In the left list of available configurations choose your current configuration and then on the right side of the dialog window in the section **Before launch** press on plus sign and choose `Run Gradle task`

[image: choose <code>Run Gradle task</code>]

In the new window choose your gradle project and in the field **Tasks** type `clean`.

[image: type <code>clean</code>]

Then move your gradle clean on top of Gradle-Aware make

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not a correct way for clean, but I made that to delete unnecessary files, and take less size of a project.
It continuously finds and deletes all build and Gradle folders
  made file **clean.bat** copy that into the folder where your project is

```
  set mypath=%cd% 
    for /d /r %mypath% %%a in (build\) do if exist "%%a" rmdir /s /q "%%a"
    for /d /r %mypath% %%a in (.gradle\) do if exist "%%a" rmdir /s /q "%%a"
```

Answer (score 0):

reed these links

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

in android studio version 2+, use this in gradle config

```
android{
..

compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        incremental = false;
}
...

}
```

after 3 days of search and test :(,  this solve "rebuild for any run"

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above works and **Build->Make** is grayed out. try this:,
First select the project and then 
Go to file->**Project_structure**
Close the window and the **Build->Make** ; will be available.
This is for 
[image]