# After adding library to android project, the XML tag is still "unallowed in Android resource files"

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, androidplot

I've been trying to add a library called 'Android Plot' into my project, however I cannot seem to get past this error. Screen shots are below. This library has worked in other test projects I have done before.

I am using Android Studio. Suggestions about how I can get past this would be great. Thanks

[image: The file tree showing that the library is added]

[image: high lighted xml code that doesn't work]

[image: Project structure showing that the library is used]

Comment: Have you done a clean/build lately?

Comment: What do you mean by this? I have done a gradlew clean from the command windows on a windows machine. I don't know what this means, but I searched around before and people have suggested to do this.

Comment: You go Project > Clean, the Project > Build

Comment: I'm using Android Studio, so it might be different than compared to ADT in Eclipse

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636848/equivalent-of-clean-build-in-android-studio

I've done what they suggested there

Comment: I've not tried AndroidStudio yet but I do use IntelliJ, which it's built on and have not had an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.  AndroidStudio is still in it's "ghetto" stage so if you try to add a library dependency in typical IntelliJ fashion you get a warning telling you that whatever you do in the project/module dialog (which shows up when you select it) actually has no effect on your build and that you must edit build.gradle manually.

In the case of Androidplot 0.5.2 heres what you do:

1. Add androidplot-core-0.5.2.jar into your /libs dir
2. In the dependencies section of build. gradle add:

   compile files('libs/androidplot-core-0.5.2.jar')

Once you've done this you should be OK.

Nick

Comment: Funny thing is, when I updated android studio, it broke the app I was working on, related to 'build.gradle'. This did fix the issue though, even though I did try this before. I guess a fresh reinstall of android studio worked.

Comment: FWIW, in the latest version of AndroidStudio simply copying the jar into /libs seems sufficient; it no longer seems to require the inclusion of a 'compile <jar-file>' line in build.gradle.