# I can not align Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I can not align LinearLayout. trying different ways but still crooked.
i need to:

### |date|name|summ|

full screen

that all parts are equal. but in fact I have the last part of a very small

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Дата"
        android:id="@+id/order_date"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#ffff343c"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ФИО"
        android:id="@+id/order_fio"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:background="#ff46ff22"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Сумма"
        android:id="@+id/order_summ"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:changed on the advice and it also does not give the desired rezulate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Дата"
        android:id="@+id/order_date"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:background="#ffff343c"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ФИО"
        android:id="@+id/order_fio"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:background="#ff46ff22"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Сумма"
        android:id="@+id/order_summ"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make width of all textview zero value: android:layout_width="0dp"

Comment: The edited xml should work....

Comment: use weightSum property in LinearLayout and give its value 3...and then try weight=1 in each TextView

Comment: @DarshilShah : weightSum is not a requirement it calculated runtime , its just informative.

Comment: @DarshilShah :I added. still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are using horizontal `layout_weight` for perfomance use :

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

and also if you want all of them equal remove `margins` and use `padding` instead.

Comment: @ValeraValerianov : try cleaning your project.

Comment: @ValeraValerianov : Cleaning the project and run it again , if using eclipse on menubar - > Project - > clean when your project is selected.

Comment: i used to Android Studio.

Comment: Editor everything correctly displayed. but when I run crooked

Comment: @ValeraValerianov : the code should work , maybe you are doing something in your code at runtime. and for cleaning in Android Studio : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636848/equivalent-of-clean-build-in-android-studio

Comment: I found a mistake. My list has been configured  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: @ValeraValerianov : good to hear issue has been solved;) thank you for accepting.