# Android runtime error with release version but not debug version

Tags: android, build.gradle, buildconfig

The following error is occurring when running the **release** version of my app, but *not* the **debug** version:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cloud3squared.meteogram/com.cloud3squared.meteogram.Meteogram}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0901e4
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0901e4
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:340)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:426)
    at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:377)
    at com.cloud3squared.meteogram.MeteogramWidgetConfigureActivity.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloud3squared.meteogram.ak.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloud3squared.meteogram.Meteogram.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
    ... 10 more
```

Any ideas why?  I have my suspicion that it may have something to do with the fact that I'm using BuildConfig values in my code, and there is [at least one suggestion](https://plus.google.com/+Gon%C3%A7aloSilva/posts/Mdd2fojUEAB) that such values are not being generated in the release version, but I've tried changing `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` in the following to a straight string value, and still it crashes.

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_version)).setText(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
```

I also make use of `buildConfigField` in my `build.gradle`:

```
buildConfigField "String", "APP_TYPE", "\"devfree\""
```

which I access all over the place as `BuildConfig.APP_TYPE`.

Incidentally, this issue (crashing with release but but debug version) only started happening when I updated everything I could in my `build.gradle` files to the latest versions, e.g.

app-level:

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
compileSdkVersion 23
defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 23
}
```

top-level:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
}
```

Before that (and if I revert to older versions), it was/is all fine.

EDIT... to answer the [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137158/android-runtime-error-with-release-version-but-not-debug-version#comment54088305_33137158), here is my complete app-level `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        development {
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'yyy'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/xxx/yyy.jks')
            storePassword 'zzz'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cloud3squared.meteogram"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 144
        versionName "1.7.14"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.development
    }
    productFlavors {
        pro {
            applicationId "com.cloud3squared.meteogram.pro"
            buildConfigField "String", "APP_TYPE", "\"pro\""
        }
        free {
            applicationId "com.cloud3squared.meteogram"
            buildConfigField "String", "APP_TYPE", "\"free\""
        }
        devpro {
            applicationId "com.cloud3squared.meteogram.devpro"
            buildConfigField "String", "APP_TYPE", "\"devpro\""
        }
        devfree {
            applicationId "com.cloud3squared.meteogram.devfree"
            buildConfigField "String", "APP_TYPE", "\"devfree\""
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
    compile project(':ambilwarna')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile project(':devmilColor')
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a clean and build? I had the same issue in past and clean-build helped me.

Comment: Is your buildConfigField specified in both your debug and release build types?

Comment: Re @Dilberted clean and build -- I'll give it a go.  I assume it's along the lines of what's described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636848/equivalent-of-clean-build-in-android-studio ?

Comment: Re @jyanks -- I've edited my question to give more of what's in the `build.gradle` file.  Whether or not the `buildConfigField` is specified for both release and development, surely if it's a problem now it should have been a problem before?

Comment: @drmrbrewer what do you see in the BuildConfig class? Are there any resouces defined in it? If possible please paste the contents here.

Comment: @Dilberted: clean and build did it!  Thanks.  And it's useful to know about the BuildConfig class... I didn't even know that such a class was generated... was just scraping the surface.  The BuildConfig class appears to be the same for release and development versions now.  If you'd like to post the answer, I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked. Just posted this as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to clean and build the project. That should fix the issue