# How to Rebuild Android Studio Project?

Tags: android-studio

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636848/equivalent-of-clean-build-in-android-studio), but under `Build` I only have `Make Selected Modules`, and `Deploy Module to App Engine`, neither which rebuilds the project. So have they moved it somewhere that I can't find? Does anyone know where I can rebuild the project?

Answer (score 8):

Go to the `Build` drop down menu in the menu bar. you can see the `Rebuild Project` under the `Clean Project`. Rebuild project cleans the project actually. If you cant find `Rebuild Project` you can simply use `Clean Project`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clean project option under build dropdown menu.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AZJ1.png)

Comment: This has already been covered by other answers