# How can I resolve "cannot find symbol ... " in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to learn android on android developer website. However I encounter an error when following their lecture. It seems that the findViewByID cannot resolve R.id.editText despite I'm just typing from their website. Can someone helps, thanks

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here is the error message: "Error:(22, 57) error: cannot find symbol variable editText".

Comment: Is this code inside an activity?

Comment: paste your whole code incl line numbers

Comment: is it your *id,editText* that showing cannot find symbol?

Comment: Yes, it is inside the MainActivity.java

Comment: Make sure you have the proper imports defined, then try rebuilding your project. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16637124/1790644). If this does not resolve the issue, you are missing the `android:id="@+id/editTex"t` line of the XML.

Comment: So the problem might be that you're missing that ID inside the manifest file

Comment: Thanks everyone, I just included the id in xml and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems that the findViewByID cannot resolve R.id.editText

You are probably missing to define `EditText` id as `editText`.

```
 <EditText
       .....
        android:id="@+id/editText"
          .....
   />
```

**YourCurrentActivity.java**

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      ......
 }
```

Comment: Which xml file should I define the editText because I don't see they includes that in the lecture

Comment: your current activity xml

Comment: Thanks, it actually works, the lecture uses design layout for xml so I forgot to check about defining the id.

Answer (score 1):

Just do one thing , remove this from **sendMessage** function and

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

place this line right below `setContentView(R.____);`
I guess , this will solve your problem