# Main Activity Error Variable cannot be found

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, program-entry-point

I am getting the error "Cannot resolve variable 'navList'". I don't understand why it can't find it navList. I would appreciate it if someone can point out where I am going wrong. Sorry for the rookie question.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

private ListView mDrawerList;

private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);

}
```

Edit -

activity_main.xml

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
```

```
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:name="com.yamini.nav.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Comment: Please post you activity_main.xml .May be your android:id is wrong.

Comment: post your xml code activity_main.xml

Comment: you don't have a `navList` in your XML.

Comment: In `mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);` this line you have error. That means id `navList` is not found in `activity_main.xml` file where your listview tag's id is different than `navList`. Therefore, add listview tag's id with `navList` name.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have posted my activity_main.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I resolve "cannot find symbol ... " in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029213/how-can-i-resolve-cannot-find-symbol-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `navList` in your xml file

By the lines in your code, it looks like you are using a fragment.

Try calling the code from your `NavigationDrawerFragment` instead, on its root View.

```
// inside NavigationDrawerFragment class
mDrawerList = (ListView)MyRootView.findViewById(R.id.navList);
```

Comment: @chocolateAndMath I assume you changed `MyRootView` to be your actual root view? What error do you see?