# Cannot clean project from android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

All the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636848/equivalent-of-clean-build-in-android-studio) point to running `Build > Clean` or `Build > Rebuild` etc. But I don't see that option in my Android Studio menu:

[image]

also running `./gradlew clean` from my command line returns:

```
$ ./gradlew clean
-bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
```

any ideas?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: The latest Android studio 2.3.3

Comment: Try `chmod +x gradlew`

Comment: please share Snaps for your project directory folder i think here Gradle file is not exist..

Comment: Look like you have not imported your project properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidating the cache located in File > Invalidate Caches, Restart