# When I try to run my JustJava coffe app it keeps stopping and will not run at all. PLEASE

Tags: android, android-studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/line1"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#040D01"
    android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft ="16dp"
    android:text="Order"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/quantity_text_view"
    android:onClick="submitOrder"
     />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

that was the xml and here is the java. at one point I had to change the end of android:context.  the end now says MainActivity but it used to say JustJava and that produced an error.  Please Help:)  This is the JustJava coffee app from udacity.  if I click in the log then this shows up as an error

> 04-25 12:09:51.410 26834-26834/com.example.android.justjava E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.android.justjava, PID: 26834
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.justjava/com.example.android.justjava.JustJava}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.justjava.JustJava" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.justjava-1/base.apk",
>   zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.justjava-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.justjava-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.justjava-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.justjava-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.justjava-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.justjava-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.justjava-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.justjava-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.justjava-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.justjava-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.justjava-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],
>   nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.justjava-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]

```
package com.example.android.justjava;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
     */
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        display(1);
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void display(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById    (R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare activity in manifest ?

Comment: Maybe you just need to clean & rebuild (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16637124/995891 I guess)